# How can I put text into a dictionary with keys that have more than one value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

My text file looks like this:

James, 10, 7, 9

Liz, 4, 6, 3

Bob, 8, 2, 5

And I have to put these into a dictionary where each name is the key and the three scores are values. 
How do I create only one dictionary and add the data to it. 
The dictionary should look like:

{'James': [10, 7, 9], 'Liz': [4, 6, 3], 'Bob': [8, 2, 5]}

At the moment my code looks like this:

with open('Class-A.txt') as f:

```
    lines = f.readlines()[0:4]

    student1_dict = {}

    key = None

    for line in lines:

        line = line.strip()

        if not key:

            key = line

            student1_dict[key] = []

        else:

            student1_dict[key].append(line)
```

print(student1_dict)

However, it outputs the data in a weird format because it is handling more than one dictionary. ??
This is the output:

{'James, 10, 7, 9': ['Liz,4,6,3', 'Bob,8,2,5', '']}

Comment: The number values will be in a list and the dict will have the exact structure you desire.

Comment: You can format the file contents and dict more appropriately by adding four spaces to the beginning of the lines. I tried to suggest an edit to do so, but apparently spaces aren't considered characters, so SO complained that the edit was too short. (I hate those limits.)

Comment: How would I create the dictionary and read the file at the same time @Walter_Ritzel .Ive tried many times to read the file at the same time but it never prints it in one dictionary or just crashes. Could you give any code suggestions or starters?

Comment: Please publish here your current code, so we can work to fix it. And also publish the text file.

Comment: I have added my current code and the problems that it has. @Walter_Ritzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get the result you want. This could be shortened and optimized greatly using more compact code but this is easier to explain step by step.

```
import csv # import the csv module to help us parse the text file


# Create an empty dictionary.
scoreDict = {}

# Open the text file to parse.
with open('sample.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    # Return an iterable reader object
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # Now we iterate through the reader object.
    for row in reader:
        if row: # Ignore empty rows
            scoresList = [] # Create an empty list we will be adding scores to.
            # We use the enumerate here to keep track of where we are in the list.
            for index, column in enumerate(row):
                if index != 0: # Ignore the first column as we use it as a key                     
                    # Turn score into an integer and add it to a list.
                    scoresList.append(int(column)) 
                    # Add the list of scores to the dictionary.
                    scoreDict[row[0]] = scoresList 

print(scoreDict)
```

Output:

```
{'Liz': [4, 6, 3], 'Bob': [8, 2, 5], 'James': [10, 7, 9]}
```

Comment: Is there a way without using csv because the data is stored in a normal text file? @Igor

Comment: The file name does not not matter. It could have as well been ``sometext.txt``. Try it on your file. csv module is in the standard library so using it wont create any dependencies either. You can do it without it also if you have to.

Comment: I finally understood the csv file bit. It works THANK U @Igor

Comment: Could you quickly give a brief explanation for what each line does. And what 'enumerate' and 'reader' does. @Igor

Comment: I have added more comments to my code to help you. You can read about  the build-in function [ennumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) and the [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.reader) at the respective links.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comp with [*csv.reader*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html), using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in python 3 to create your key/value pairings:

```
from csv import reader

with open("in.csv") as f:
    dct = {k: list(map(int, rest)) for k,*rest in reader(f, skipinitialspace=1)}
    print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'Bob': [8, 2, 5], 'Liz': [4, 6, 3], 'James': [10, 7, 9]}
```

You don't strictly need `skipinitialspace` as `int` can take care of  whitespace but if you wanted to keep the values as strings you would add it or you would have leading whitespace before the digits.

If you were to use python2, the syntax would be slightly different but still concise, you would just need to slice/index:

```
from csv import reader

with open("in.csv") as f:
    dct = {row[0]: map(int,row[1:]) for row in reader(f, skipinitialspace=1)}
```

If you have empty lines you just need to add an `if row`:

```
dct = {row[0]: map(int,row[1:]) for row in reader(f, skipinitialspace=1) if row}
```

And for python3:

```
with open("in.csv") as f:
    rd =  reader(f, skipinitialspace=1)
    dct = {k: list(map(int, rest)) for k, *rest in filter(None, rd)}
    print(dct)
```

If you want to use a for loop the logic is the same, no need for multiple loops, indexing and slicing is a very basic task in python:

```
from csv import reader

with open("in.csv") as f:
    dct = {}
    for row in reader(f, skipinitialspace=1):
        # if we have data
        if row:
            # index first element to get the key then
            # slice from the first element to the end casting to int
            dct[row[0]] = map(int,row[1:])
    print(dct)
```

The python3 code can be turned into something similar following the same logic.

Comment: from csv import reader                                                                                              with open('Class-A.txt') as f:                                                                                                         dct = {row[0]:map(int,row[1:]) for row in reader(f, skipinitialspace=1)}

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel. Would this be the correct way. However it is still giving an error. Now the list index is out of range. ??

Comment: The problem is with any blank lines in the file... Let me see what can be done to solve it.

Comment: @Minions, do you have empty lines in the file? If you do the last edit will work.